# Careers jobs listing - back to top

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, navigation, browsers

I've been looking on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs# recently and I found out that when browsing the listing, clicking on 2 (page 2) or next (or other pages) does not return to the top of the listing.

It's pretty not cool to stay at the bottom of the page.

By the way, the 'jump to top of page' behavior exists and is implemented when you click back on 1 (page 1) or previous from page 2.

Could it be generalised?

#### Edit:

See comments: the problem arises with firefox. Different browser have different behaviour.

By the way, other question listing in SO, SU or meta does not show the problem. Is it a different implementation?

Comment: You're using Firefox, correct?

Comment: Yes. Didn't tried other browser. I will.

Comment: S'ok, I already did :)

Comment: Confirmed. IE does go top with centered page. Opera goes top aligned on the right edge. Chrome goes up aligning listing div on the left edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks, this should be all set.

Comment: Seems good on FireFox!! Thanks!